# How can I get the path of the previous url?

Tags: php, symfony

I was wondering how can I get the path of the previous url?

May someone enlighten me.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` in php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return the last response (the previous page where you have been) just do this:

```
return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
```

If you want to get just the path do this:

```
$request->headers->get('referer');
```

If you have been e.g. in

***www.example.com/a*** and the you go to 
***www.example.com/a/b***

If you call the referer from "B" it will be: ***www.example.com/a***

Comment: Question: How do I go about instantiating the $request object? Is it a service?

Comment: Is there a way to access this inside a page Controller? If i have a controller at /a and i have a link to it in /b. If something fails in /a controller code i want to spit out a msg and return to /b; but $request->headers->get('referer'); points to /a.

Comment: super late reply sorry but yes you instantiate: like public function methodName(Request $request) been $request an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation

Answer (score 3):

I used for TWIG :

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') != app.request.headers.get('referer') %}    
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.headers.get('referer') }}" />    
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\Drupal::request()->headers->get('referer');`

Remember if using this within `formState::setRedirect()`, or another function that is expecting a route to be passed, to load the route from the referral URL string...also, look our for route parameters if the referrer has them.

Unless you want to catch all route parameter possiblities, you probably need a fallback.

EG ( the below is just an example, check my code :) ):

```
$ref_url_string = \Drupal::request()->headers->get('referer');
// $ref_url_string is absolute, you may need to get just the path (part after <domain>)
$url_object = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid($ref_url_string));
$route_name = $url_object->getRouteName();
$node_route_param = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

// Then call it with the route, and maybe param.
// No route param.
$form_state->setRedirect($route_name);

// With route param.
$form_state->setRedirect($route_name, ['node' => $node_route_param->id()]);
```

Comment: This is the right answer for Drupal 8 and above. (There is an extra closed parentheses  on line 3, but there are too many pending edits so I can not fix it).